# Laravel Cashier undefined method meteredPrice()

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, laravel-cashier

I try to use a meteredPrice() function with Laravel Cashier. For what I need it - for example if I sign subscription in 01.06, I want to make payment at 01.07, so after 1 month.
For this I tried to use meteredPrice() like at the documentation, but get an error "Call to undefined method Laravel\Cashier\SubscriptionBuilder::meteredPrice()"

```
$request->user()->newSubscription($plan_id, [])
                ->meteredPrice($value)
                ->create($paymentMethodId->main_payment_method);
```

The similar code with immideatelly paying works fine:

```
$request->user()->newSubscription($plan_id, $value)
                ->create($paymentMethodId->main_payment_method);
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a version of `laravel/cashier-stripe` lower than 13.0?

Only since 13.0, ["plans" are renamed to "prices"](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-stripe/blob/73ef56b8b15205cc1251f0f86d3470591a8ef12e/UPGRADE.md#renaming-plans-to-prices). Try:

```
$request->user()->newSubscription($plan_id, [])
    ->meteredPlan($value)
    ->create($paymentMethodId->main_payment_method);
```